# Can a buried electric line cross a buried sewer line?

Tags: electrical

What are the code requirements for crossing a buried electric line (from meter to panel) with a sewage line?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How deep is the sewage line and the potential electric line? A diagram might be helpful...

Comment: Is the electrical line direct buried, or in conduit?  Which line is the existing one, and which line is being added?

Comment: Is the sewer line PVC or cast iron? There could be a difference

Comment: You should [edit] your question with the answer to all these questions

Comment: Code requirements will depend on **your specific location,** and the code that is in effect there. That said, it happens all the time. It's **a good idea** to consider upgrading the protection and marking of the electric line in the area of the sewer line crossing, but it may not be **required** to do so. Code sets *minimum* standards, and sometimes it makes sense to aim a little higher than that.

Comment: Are you worries about 'clean' energy?

Answer (score 0):

Here it's not an issue:  Sewer lines have to be below frost line, so they are put at 8 feet.  Electrical lines are, I think 3 feet, and can be less if protected.  This of course makes it difficult to run a sewer line after the electrical is in.

I would try very hard to keep buried lines from crossing.  SOMETIME one is going to be dug up for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Code is whatever local ordinances tell you that you can do.   It isn't good to cross lines but there has to be thousands of examples where you would have to so obviously it is done.   Whether it is a use case, safety, or other type of reason needed is up to your local city in the US.